# What do you have to check for Shatnez?

Tags: halacha, clothing, inspection, shaatnez

What do you and what do you not have to check for Shatnez?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17198/1569

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27869

Answer (score 6):

http://shatnez.n3.net/ Here are a few:

Carpets/Rugs: May require testing. Wool carpets (wall-to-wall) and area rugs may be backed or reinforced with linen. Non-woolen rugs and carpets are not a problem. Services are available at most shatnez laboratories for those who wish to have their carpets tested.

Linen and Linen-look fabrics: Require testing.

Pajamas: Do not require testing.

Suits and Sport jackets, (Men's/Boy's): Require testing even 100% polyester and 100% silk suits.

Suits/Jackets (Women's): Only fully constructed suits require testing. "Linen-look" fabrics or those labeled as containing "other fibers" should be tested.

Ties: Linen and polyester ties with a textured surface ties need testing. Silk ties are generally free of shatnez, except for those from Spain (even 100% silk).

Trousers/Slacks/Pants: Those made in the USA have not been found to contain shatnez. All imported trousers should be tested. Any trousers which have a linen-look fabric should be checked, even if American made.

For more info- this site has an entire list with almost every item.

If anyone is looking for Hilchot Shatnez (in Hebrew) [Yalkut.info-hilchot shatnez](http://yalkut.info/Table/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D/) has the entire Yalkut Yosef Halachot. Also, it gives pretty much the same list as ST of America.

Comment: Although just copying and pasting is not ok, its also not ideal to just have a link. Perhaps list some of the more common items, and then say that there are many more at the following link.

Comment: @HachamGabriel Why tsu al di reykhes would you need to have a carpet/rug tested for shatnetz? You aren't wearing it...

Answer (score 6):

[Rav Aaron Abadi writes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906074359/http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=52091):

"Don't listen to the rumors. There is no need to check for Shaatnez on any article of clothing unless you're sure there's shaatnez in there.
For all those who need to know....
Shaatnez according to some Rishonim requires "Shua, Tavi, and Nuz all together." We don't have that today. So according to those Rishonim, today's Shaatnez is only derabanan. When you bring a suit home, you only have a Safek Derabanan that is not "efsher levrury bekal." Or you can see it as a Sefek sefeka on a de'oraita. Same difference.
The current so-called Shaatnez awareness was not initiated by Talmidei Chachamim. May sound radical. Probably because it is. "

Also, the Mishneh Halachos ([7:198](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1879&pgnum=271)) writes similarly that without any indication on the label that there is shatnez, there is no need to be machmir and check for shatnez.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think that Mishne Halachat is talking about checking mattresses...

Comment: @HachamGabriel That is his initial question, but he goes on to talk about Sha'atnez in general.

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted opinion holds that by an issur one should be choshesh for a "miut ha'motzoi", which I think R.H. Schachter defines as around 10%. So if you think the suit has a greater than 10% chance of being shatnez, you should get it checked. If so, I think only certain higher-end wool suits would be an issue. Some might hold one should check it even if its not a "miut hamotzoi" if its something that's very easy to do. Either way, once one suit from a line was checked, I don't see why there's any reason to check other ones. Its extremely unlikely that the manufacturer made a sudden change in the production of the same suit. So if there was a list of kosher suits, one could just check that.

Comment: Re high-end wool suits: I have encountered many a shatnez-laden lower-end suit produced in the '50s, '60s and '70s.

Comment: What about 100% wool (especially fine wool) sweaters? The likelihood that they also contain linen is extremely small, and whenever I do get them checked the checker generally looks at the tag, does a quick scan with his eyes, and hands it back to me saying it's fine (usually without charging, either). Is there a way for a lay person to recognize problem sweaters vs. good sweaters? If the label says 100% wool, can that be trusted as excluding linen (among all other materials)?

Comment: @SethJ AFAIK if you have small percentage of certain material you do not obligated to report that on label. So, for example, if parts of wool sweater are sewn linen strings this info could be omitted from label.

Comment: @jutky Right, but then why does it seem like the checker barely needs to glance at it? Why, when checking suits, do they only check certain parts that are commonly problematic and not analyze every stitch?

Comment: @SethJ I don't know what to tell you about the checker. But about suits, they check only certain parts where linen might be used. You don't have to suspect a problem in case of "מיעות שאינו מצוי". So, as far as I understand checkers more rely on common practices of suits production and not on labels marking

Comment: @jutky Shouldn't the same then be true for sweaters?

Comment: Dear Ariel: Can you cite any rabbi to support your post? Because R' Yirmiyohu Kaganoff disagrees with you. See his article ["When Must I Check for Shatnez?"](http://baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=8943). He looks at the sources and finds that, regarding garments, they aren't choshesh only for a _mi'ut hamatzuy_.

Comment: -1. A) R' Yirmiyohu Kaganoff disagrees with your first point. See his article ["When Must I Check for Shatnez?"](http://baltimorejewishlife.com/news/news-detail.php?SECTION_ID=1&ARTICLE_ID=8943). He looks at the sources and finds that, regarding garments, they aren't choshesh only for a _mi'ut hamatzuy_. B) See [this post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27985), s.vv. "It usually differs even from one identical suit to the next". C) Dear Ariel: Could you please edit your post and remove your theory about identical suits? D) Also, can you cite any rabbi to support your remaining points?

Answer (score 3):

I think generally speaking, if you'd reasonably believe it could contain wool or linen.

I heard something about baseball mitts being a problem?  Anyone hear of this?

From what I've heard, a garment that's entirely cotton and/or synthetic is incredibly unlikely to contain both wool and linen (but men's suits could still have lining or padding or the like ...?).  Usually what people have checked (again, if I understand correctly) is clothing claiming a certain percentage to be either "wool", "linen", or "other" (which could be anything).

Comment: Does anyone have any sources

Comment: I've heared once a lecture of someone from a Shaatnez Lab and he told same things: If the cloths contain wool or linen they should be checked (he didn't mentioned "other", but it seems reasonable to include it too). However, I don't remember the lecturer's name.

Answer (score 0):

There exist various guides online which answer the question. [This guide](http://www.hakhel.info/archivesShatnez/ShatnezGuideJune10.pdf), from the [Hakhel website](http://www.hakhel.info/Shatnez.htm), seems to be the most complete English-language guide online. It includes a detailed chart plus four pages of color photos. It's definitely more complete than the guide which Hacham Gabriel linked to in his answer above.

When in doubt, [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi). The shatnez tester in my city once told me that, in cases of doubt, it's best for each person to ask his own decisor. If the decisor is unsure, he will refer the querent to the local shatnez tester.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding sefek sefeka of d'Oraissa, not every machlokes haposkim will create a valid sofek. Furthermore, the actual presence of detectable issur may not be a classical sofek at all. This is not like taref ingredients which are mixed in and undetectable except to a sophisticated palate.

Mi'ut ha'matzui is appropriate here, according to many poskim. Treifos, and insect infestation, are similar cases.

How is a few dollars added to the cost of a $200+ garment not 'efshar l'vrurei b'kal?

Iirc, suits from the same line, bought off the same rack, have been found to have different threads, or collar stiffeners, etc. The factories are not particular about these things, they use whatever is available, and can 'mix and match'.

See link below
http://matzav.com/why-relying-on-sample-testing-for-shatnez-is-no-good

Comment: Do you check your shirts, socks, yarmulka, chair, or couch? Do you think that professionals check every last thread of your jacket?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbi Golfeiz of the STAR-K [lists](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/5279/getting-into-the-fabric-of-shatnez-checking-with-a-man-of-the-cloth/):

a) Expensive wool scarves – Linen may have been used to stitch the seam of the scarf so it would be a good idea to check.

b) Wool or linen ties – Need to be checked

c) Wool socks – At one time, Gold Toe socks did contain Shatnez; however, I have not recently found this to be so.

d) Polyester suit – The shoulder pads, stiffening collar and other internal parts (e.g., pockets, etc.) should be checked.

e) Silk ties – Do not need to be checked

f) Plain wool caps – Do need to be checked

g) Russian hats made of fur – These should be checked because the lining inside the hat could, and often does, use a natural fabric such as wool or linen. The same applies to Russian wool army jackets. Countries behind the Iron Curtain frequently used linen as part of the internal linings of garments.

h) Pillows that state they are stuffed with “unknown fabric” need to be checked, including Bed Rest Pillows.

i) Products listing “Unknown Fibers” – should be avoided.