# How to check your own Shaatnez

Tags: product-recommendation, how-to, inspection, shaatnez

Is there a guide or a maybe a video on how to check your own clothes for Shaatnez? Does anyone here know? If so, can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the section](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7740&st=&pgnum=122) in Shimushah Shel Torah dealing with it. (It's illustrated.)

Comment: Can you summarize?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1890/5323