# Does a 3% angora sweater have to be tested for shatnez?

Tags: halacha, clothing, shaatnez

Does a sweater that has 3% angora and all other synthetic fibers have to be checked if it has no appliques?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Remember to treat any advice from this site as if it came from a crowd of your friends, and not a rabbinical authority. For a definitive ruling, please contact your rabbi. You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Do you mean that it's *labeled* has having 3% angora and the rest synthetic, or that it really *is* 3% angora and the rest synthetic? I hate to nitpick, but I assume you mean the former, but then good answers would address manufacturing processes and label honesty, which the answer below does not. So either I'm misunderstanding your intent or the answerer below is; can you clarify it, please, by [edit]ing the question?

Answer (score 2):

Angora, rabbit fur, is not included in the type of wool to which the laws of shatnez apply. See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 298 siff one.

And just for next time, camel hair and cashmere are also completely absolved from any Shatnez worries, even on a rabbinic level.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18923/759