# Shiur of "Miut Hamatzui"

Tags: sources-mekorot, shiurim-measurements

A "miut hamatzui" is a phrased used to express a case where because of a small concern that something exists, or might happened, or does happen that the halacha is affected by this. An example is if there is a certain type of "treifah" by a kosher animal that is found in a small amount therefore this must be checked after that animal is shechted.

However what is the amount of a "miut hamatzui"? What are the different opinions in this?

(I don't feel my explanation of a "miut hamaztui" is adequate enough however it's difficult for me to express in English. Perhaps someone can edit it.)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11570/759

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks. But, makor? (aside from R' Shechter)

Comment: @Yehoshua The generally cited mekor is the *Mishk'nos Ya'akov* ([Vol. 1, YD § 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1095&pgnum=208)).

Comment: @Fred Sounds like an answer. However any other opinions, b'frat from earlier sources?

Comment: It would be interesting to compare this to the pyschological studies on the same topic.

Answer (score 6):

Miut Hamatui has four opinions as brought down in the new Yalkut Yosef.

1) Rav Shelomo Zalman Aurbach who holds it is around 10%.

2) Shevet HaLevi who holds it is even less but doesn't specify.

3) Rav Bension Aba Shaul who says around 17%.

4) The opinion of the Rivash and Hacham Yishak Yosef Shelit"a who hold that it is much closer to 50% but doesn't specify.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Nice answer.

Comment: Do you have the sources for all of these statements?

Comment: 50%? We know cow lungs aren't that bad

Comment: I'm pretty sure _Shevet Halevi_ (4:81, 8:180) specifically says that there is not a hard-and-fast percentage that defines the dependability of a _mi'ut_.

Comment: Are you the same person as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1035/hacham-gabriel? If so, you may want to look into unifying this new account with the original, registered account.

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/why-do-sephardi-jews-put-on-the-tefillin-shel-yad-while-sitting/34089#comment87327_34089

Answer (score 5):

Rav Eitam Henkin provides sources for all the various opinions on pages 39-62 of [this kuntres](http://www.michtavim.com/EitamHenkin5770.pdf).

Comment: please summarize the points incase the link goes bad.

Comment: THE LINK DOSENT WORKֱֱֱ

Answer (score 5):

Many poskim put it at 10% -- thank you Fred, Mishkenos Yaakov 1:YD17 first puts it that way. (See Rabbi JD Bleich's "Is the Milk We Drink Kosher?" in *Tradition*). This is the general OU opinion.

We find the figure of 10% by combining a law in *Terumot* -- about whether you must check that a bottle of wine in the case has spoiled before taking *terumah* from the batch -- with a law in *Bava Basra* -- about 10% being the normal spoilage rate when selling a case of wine.

The next question becomes -- 10% of *what*? Do I say "so long as the odds of eating a bug is <10% in this serving of lettuce, I can eat this serving"? Or perhaps we need "so long as the odds of finding a bug in this bag is <10%, I can buy this bag"? Or perhaps we even need "I can buy this *case* of lettuce without checking only if the odds of finding a bug anywhere in it are <10%"?