# Experimental drug testing (e.g. for cancer)

Tags: medicine, responsa

Are there any sources discussing (both l'kula and l'chumra) experimental drug studies? Two reasons this would be halachically problematic:

1. Drugs assigned based on animal studies have a small chance of successfully curing the patient, and a significant chance of causing harm.
2. Correct dosages are often determined by raising dosages until 50% of patients experience some toxic effect. In this sense, there is a kavua 50% chance of inflicting harm at this stage of the study.

Sources directly discussing this question, or sources on other topics that you think would be relevant are welcome. Hebrew preferred.

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/maaliyot/veim-2.htm

Comment: Terrific source - thanks! My main question, which is not quite answered here, is: can we administer a treatment with serious risk to the individual, for the benefit of the research program which could save a multitude of others?

Comment: Which side of this would be l'kula and which would be l'chumra?

Comment: Do you know how widely the 50% standard applies? Because I recall reading about an exceptionally effective hepatitis C drug that was nixed in 2008 after phase II trials showed signs of liver toxicity in 8% of patients (which is lower than the rate of liver damage from the disease itself).

Comment: @Daniel, good point. I meant to say "pro or con".

Comment: @Fred, the number is based on an informal discussion with an oncologist, and may be inaccurate. Suppose it is x% where x > 2.

Comment: @user67771 Well, it may make a halachic difference. For example, the *Mishk'nos Ya'akov* says that a *mi'ut hamatzui* is 10% or greater. See also [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27862).

Comment: @Fred, excellent point. I will try to find out, but I think the answer would be interesting in all cases.

Comment: AFAIK, the LD 50 standard for dosing is NEVER applied to human subjects, as that would be a major violation of both ethics and law. LD 50 is only used in animal testing, and extrapolated to upper limits of dosage per kg of body weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rabbi Dr. Akiva Tatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_Tatz) discusses general principles of medical halacha in [this lecture](http://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/principles-of-medical-halacha/). Here are some things that he said that are relevant to your question:

A person is obligated, as a patient, to get the best medical treatment that he can. A doctor is obligated to give the best medical treatment available.

(~50 minutes) You're only allowed to pursue medicine that is widely accepted by broad selections of your generation. That said, what is the definition of "widely accepted"? Conventional Western medicine clearly fits the bill. However, it's not perfect -- there are some things that it's "shockingly poor at." You're allowed to do it, because it's an accepted standard. Homeopathy (though it may not always make sense) is "broadly enough accepted that it's permissible."

(~54 minutes) The first thing to consider is the practical -- has all the homework been done? It's not a good idea to be the first person to use a drug that hasn't been researched properly, to put it lightly. However, according to [Rabbi Moshe Feinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein)*, if (1) the homework has been done and (2) there is a consensus of expert medical opinion that this is worth the risk, a person is *allowed* (though not required) to pursue an experimental cure.

---

Although, of course, these are just the basic rules, and each case needs to be investigated by a rabbi on its own merits.

I strongly recommend that you listen to the lecture; if not for the content, then for Rabbi Tatz's *wonderful* South African accent :P

* *Possibly the teshuva mentioned in my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52879/5323).*

Comment: Note that in that lecture, he uses very broad terms and doesn't go into specifics all that much (and no sources `:(`), but I think this is enough to answer the question.

Comment: [This lecture](http://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/dangerous-therapy-risks-in-medicine/) may also be relevant, but I haven't listened to it yet.

Comment: Thanks! I too would be very happy to find that R' Moshe teshuva.

Comment: @user67771 I *may* have located the teshuva; see my revised answer. It's not *exactly* what Rabbi Tatz said it was, so in actuality it's probably *not* the correct one.