Can a Talmid Chacham pasken something isn’t shaatnez for himself
According to this answer, the Taz believes that a Talmid Chacham has the right to pasken for himself, however there is an exception if something has a previous status of prohibition. Can a Talmid Chacham pasken for himself that something is presumed to not be shaatnez using Chazaka under this logic, or since the previous status of whether it is shaatnez is unknown is that not valid  in Halacha?

What does pasken for himself something is not shaatnez mean? Shaatnez is a reality - either it's wool and linen or it isn't. I'm lost.

see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126687/why-do-we-check-clothing-for-shaatnez-isnt-it-a-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%98-%d7%a9%d7%90%d7%a0%d7%95-%d7%9e%d7%a6%d7%95%d7%99
